# Getting error while resizing the image and writing it with cv2 package

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Getting error while resizing the image and writing it with cv2 package. I don't know why this error is occurring.

The code is

```
image = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
image_resize = cv2.resize(image, (4600, 5500))
cv2.imwrite(image, image_resize)
```

error is

```
cv2.imwrite(image, image_resize)
TypeError: Can't convert object of type 'numpy.ndarray' to 'str' for 'filename'
```

Comment: The error is very instructive. It's telling you that, on the third line, you are giving np.ndarray where the function is expecting a file name. so instead of image you need 'image.jpg.

Comment: But It'll save the image into local pc right. I don't want to save the file, I just just want to resize and run.

Comment: then dont call imwrite at all? The only purpose of that function is to save an image to disk

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using a different filename for in the `cv2.imwrite()` statement, rather than the same filename as the original. For example:

```
cv2.imwrite("new_image.jpg", image_resize)
```

Comment: Can't we run without saving the image? I mean the changes should be made within the code itself.

Comment: @Nithin Reddy I'd imagine that it would be possible if you just needed the resized image data for something else within your code, as you are storing it in a variable, but if you are wanting to save the image to your computer then you will need to do the `cv2.imwrite` statement to save it.

Answer (score 0):

The error says the answer:

> Can't convert object of type 'numpy.ndarray' to 'str'

Means the first parameter should be a string but you are providing array.

You need to give `image_name` i.e.

```py
image_name = "image_resize.png"

cv2.imwrite(image_name, image_resize)
```

For more you can [read](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-imwrite-method/)

---

If you want to run, then you can do:

```py
image = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
image_resize = cv2.resize(image, (4600, 5500))
cv2.imshow("image_resize", image_resize)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This will display image, showing the output.