# Can't convert object of type 'JpegImageFile' to 'str' for 'filename'

Tags: python, django, numpy, django-models, python-imaging-library

[image]

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    # open image
    pil_img = Image.open(self.pic)

    # convert the image to array and do some processing
    cv_img = np.array(pil_img)
    img = main(pil_img)

    # convert back to pil image
    im_pil = Image.fromarray(img)

    # save
    buffer = BytesIO()
    im_pil.save(buffer, format='png')
    image_png = buffer.getvalue()

    self.pic.save(str(self.pic), ContentFile(image_png), save=False)

    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

can't understand what's wrong with it.
i even tried to comment the cv_img = np.array(pil_img) but it still fail to run

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66232430/14457833) to your question ?

Comment: Your last two lines of code make no sense at all to me? Delete them :P
IIUC, the error indicates that self.pic is not a string but a JpegImageFile object.
Try `im_pil.save("myfile.png")`

Comment: there is no OpenCV. there is only numpy and PIL and django.